# Get feeds of user whom we are following

Tags: laravel, getstream-io

How to get the list of feeds/activities for users whom we are following.

I tried `$user_feed_1->following(10, 20);` but not getting feed data like we get in  `$user_feed_1->getActivities(5, 10);`

I am using Laravel framework. I am not getting any error but getting output  **array***(size=4)*  'created_at' =>string'2016-04-29T04:14:49.416Z'*(length=24)*  'feed_id' =>string'flat:1986'*(length=9)*  'target_id' =>string'user:6028'*(length=9)*  'updated_at' =>string'2016-04-29T04:14:49.416Z'*(length=24)*

Not the output as for feed

Comment: Please elaborate, what language and package are you using, does the presented code return an error, an empty list, throws an exception etc. Also show how you initialize the client and feed.

Comment: @ Matthisk please see the edited question

Comment: @Matthisk any help please

Comment: @Matthisk I am trying to get feeds using $flatFeed = FeedManager::getNewsFeed($user->id)['flat']; but not getting feeds to the users whom I am following, it only shows my feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the list of users, and not the follow connections created for their feeds, you should store the follow connections in your database as well.

The official [laravel example apps](https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-PHP/) does exactly this, it stores follow connections between users and sends API calls whenever those connections are created or destroyed. You can see how that's done by looking at the `Follow` model in the code of the example.

Comment: I wants all feeds for all users whom we are following.

Comment: I used following code to follow user :$followFlatFeed = \FeedManager::getClient()->feed('flat', $follow->target_id);
                //$followFlatFeed = \FeedManager::feed('flat', $follow->target_id);
                $followFlatFeed->followFeed('user', $follow->user_id);   For reterving I used following $feed = \FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($user_id)['flat'];
             $activities = $feed->getActivities(0, 100); But I am not getting feeds of user whom I am following

Comment: i am not geting following useres feeds using above .