# Get following users feed

Tags: getstream-io

I am trying to get all activites of the users whom I am following i.e.

Suppose I am following two users A and B, so I want all activities of these useres.

I have done following (laravel framework) :

suppose my id is $user_id and user whom I am following have id $target_id

To follow user I used following :

```
\FeedManager::followUser($user_id, $target_id);
// following  flat feed of user whom I am following
$followFlatFeed = \FeedManager::getClient()->feed('flat', $target_id);
// following user feed
$followFlatFeed->followFeed('user', $user_id);
```

To get the all feeds of following user I have used following code:

```
$feed = \FeedManager::getNewsFeeds($user_id)['flat'];
$activities = $feed->getActivities(0, 1000);
```

But I  am getting only my own feeds not for the user whom I following

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930149/get-feeds-of-user-whom-we-are-following

Answer (score 1):

The example above will create the reversed follow relation of `$target_id` -> follows -> `$user_id`. If I understand you correctly you want the follow relationship `$user_id` -> follows -> `$target_id`.

Comment: This is not working. I am also getting my own activities not other user activities whom I am following.